# Construct an actor-by-clique matrix after kCliques in RBGL

Tags: r, matrix, package, igraph

After running `kCliques` in `RBGL`, I have a list comprised of cliques and their members.

I wish to construct a member-by-clique matrix from the list object created by `kCliques`.

As an example:

```
con <- file(system.file("XML/snacliqueex.gxl",package="RBGL"))
coex <- fromGXL(con)
close(con)
kcl <- kCliques(coex)
```

which results in

```
kcl<-structure(list(`1-cliques` = list(c("1", "2", "3"), c("2", "4"), 
    c("3", "5"), c("4", "6"), c("5", "6")), `2-cliques` = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6")), 
    `3-cliques` = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))), 
    .Names = c("1-cliques", "2-cliques", "3-cliques"))
```

`kcl` is a list where elements are character vectors indicating clique members.
I wish to construct a member-by-clique matrix where cell i,j indicates whether node i is a member of clique j.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the expected matrix for this particular input should be. Are you collecting all the 1-, 2-, and 3-cliques? What is the range of `j` values for this example?

Comment: In the example, the range j values would be 8: the number of k-cliques discovered by kcl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some transformations that should work

```
#remove one level of nesting
x <- do.call("c", kcl);
#assign number to each cliqeq
xx <- do.call("rbind", Map(function(x,y) data.frame(x,y), x, seq_along(x))); 
#track participation
xtabs(~x+y, xx)
```

which gives

```
   y
x   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
  2 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
  3 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
  4 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
  5 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
  6 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
```